# Transfer XBL Gold License

Tags: xbox-360

My fiancée recently bought a gold membership and a couple weeks later decided she didn't want it.

Is it possible to transfer her gold membership to my account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to customer support, it's not possible to transfer the XBL Gold License, to another account.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, unfortunately.